# Tried basically everything and still cannot dual-boot

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi

I wanted to dual boot Ubuntu and Windows for deep learning. I downloaded the latest LTS iso and flashed it onto a flash drive using Rufus. Then, I restarted the computer and went into BIOS. I booted from the USB and started the installer. I had previously made a partition on the hard drive(I have an SSD and a HDD) of about 50 GB. I tried installing on that partition, but then I get an error saying that the GRUB installer errored out. So, I tried disabling fast boot and trying again. I even tried creating a separate FAT32 partition for EFI and manually set the GRUB installation location to that partition(this is on the partition). I even made sure /dev/sda pointed to the SSD and /dev/sdb pointed to the HDD. Still got the same error. No idea what I should do. Please help out...

Answer (score 1):

I would try making the partition for Ubuntu in the installer and not beforehand.

Leave your 50GB partition as free space, and in the Ubuntu installer create a 50GB partition formatted as an ext4 journaling file system, mounted on /, if you want you can create multiple partitions for the other mount points, although its not needed and you can just have them in one partition. Also you can create a swap partition, I would make it the same mb as your installed ram.

The grub installation location thing at the bottom left of the installer window, just leave it as it is and it should make a folder for grub2 in the efi partition created by windows.

Comment: That's the problem, grub2 installation isn't working...